# Using older version of RTF

Tags: ms-word, vb6, rtf

Need to use older version of RTF without overwriting the MS Word version

Hi
I have a system that was developed in VB6 (Shortly to be rewritten in VB.NET) which uses rtf documents saved from MS Word 2002 which I scan to isolate certain details and change them.  The user now wants to upgrade to MS Word 2010 but this causes problems within my system because it uses a later version of RTF.  Is there any way that I can take the .DOC or .DOCX inputs and run them through an earlier version of RTF?  I do not mind the fact that it will drop some functionality.
Regards
Mac

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DocX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocX/) to read the data you need directly or possibly down-convert the documents.

You might need to make the DLL COM-visible (DocX source code is available on GitHub) or write a wrapper DLL that is COM-visible so this can be used in VB6.

This approach should save you time when you rewrite the app in VB.NET.